# 12.04 Install Stuck On 2 Out Of 5 Dots

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi, windows-vista

I've been trying to install Ubuntu for a while on my old Windows Vista laptop. I have successfully installed it onto my Windows 7 computer with no problem. I couldn't find any info on this though but when I'm trying to install, it hangs at 2 out of the 5 dots.

I've tried WUBI and 3 different disks with no help. Does anybody know how to fix this?

It does this after I try to boot from CD.

Comment: Please edit your answer with the computer specs: brand,model,graphic card(s).

Answer (score 0):

[Check the CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck#Verifying_the_CD.2BAC8-DVD_Integrity) and [verify the iso image you downloaded](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). This will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this by uninstalling unity and installing gdm

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove unity

sudo apt-get install gdm

It works in ubuntu 12.04